# Word forms - display a form value in text below the form

Tags: ms-word

how to display a value from MS Word Form.

Eg:

I have a form with one dropdown list with following values:

DropDown1: a, b, c

When I select value a, I want to display the value in plain text. Eg:

Value of the selected field is: a.

I would prefere not to use vba.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the (assuming DropDown1 is a ComboBox control) ComboBox's Change routine.

```
Private Sub DropDown1_Change()
    Selection.TypeText DropDown1.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Ad I said. I would prefer not to use vba. Thanks.

Comment: I can't see how you could achieve it without using VBA

Answer (score 1):

If it is a "legacy form" (not a form with ActiveX controls or content controls, then

a. set the properties of the dropdown to calculate on exit, and the "bookmark" to (say) dropdown1.

b. put a { REF dropdown1 } field in the document where you want the value

c. protect the form in the usual way.

The value will only appear when the user tabs out of the dropdown.

It's not exactly "plain text", but it's not a form field either. If you need "genuine plain text", you would need code.

If it is a content control, then you would need to set up a Custom XML part and link the dropdown to it, then insert a plain text content control that was also linked to the same element/attribute in that part. That requires code at design time (or a third party add-in, or Word 2013) but not at run time.